# Showing backing bean HTML data as it is without any wrapper extra tags in JSF

Tags: html, jsf-2, richfaces

I am using JSF for my application.

I have a dynamic string which act as a propert html tag combination data.That data is stored in my bean rulesBean.
I can easily shown that bean's data as html elements using,

```
     <h:outputLabel escape="false" value="#{rulesBean.myData}"/>
```

But,above lines creates extra html tags i.e  and put all bean data inside it.I dont want these extra wrapper tags.I just want to put whatevr i have in bean.So,i have to do like :

```
         #{rulesBean.myData}
```

But,this line shows the html values as it is as text.I want to convert that text into proper html layout with out adding extra wrapper.

How to achive that in JSF ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
<h:outputText escape="false" value="#{rulesBean.myData}" />
```

note. as soon as you use any 'style' attributes it will render inside a `<span>`

http://www.jsftoolbox.com/documentation/help/12-TagReference/html/h_outputText.html

Comment: thanks for your reply.<h:outputText> is still render inside <tr><td> which i dont want.So this soluation is not working for me.

Comment: probably because it is inside a dataTable, dataGrid right? Can you post the full page?